# issue with memory warning in swift

Tags: uicollectionview, filesystems, swift3

i have save images on png extension and the video on the mp4 in file system when i need to display images i fetch all url from document directory and display it on the collection view   its work  but i need to display frame of video and images from document directory on the collection view i do it but i get the memory warning i don't know why please any help

the following my code:

```
// this function for the get video frame and display it on the collection view 
func generateThumnail(url : NSURL, fromTime:Float64) -> UIImage {


            let asset :AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url as URL)
            let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
            assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
            let time        : CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, 600)
            let img:CGImage = try! assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            let frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: img)
            return frameImg

    }
```

// and this is for collection view

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrayOfUrl.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowPhotoAlbumCell

            if self.arrayOfUrl[indexPath.row].pathExtension == "mp4" {
                let grabTime = 0.50
                let img = self.generateThumnail(url: self.arrayOfUrl[indexPath.row] as NSURL, fromTime: Float64(grabTime))
                cell.imageViewCell.image = img
                cell.imageViewVideo.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.imageViewCell.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.arrayOfUrl[indexPath.row].path)
                cell.imageViewVideo.isHidden = true
            }


        return cell
    }
```

// and this is for array which contain All urls form document directory

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        arrayOfUrl = []
        if let getImages = WorkingWithFileSystem.fetchAllImagesFromDocumentDirectory(folderName: folderName) {
            arrayOfUrl = getImages
        }


      collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

please can fix this problem without memory warning

thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let img = self.generateThumnail(url: self.arrayOfUrl[indexPath.row] as NSURL, fromTime: Float64(grabTime))
cell.imageViewCell.image = img
```

with

```
cell.imageViewCell.image = UIImage(named: "thumbnail")!
```

Sorry , but I think you have to try with some static image for thumbnail and then check.. may be `generateThumnail` is leaking memory in collection view `cellForItemAt` method while generating thumbnail image for large sizes video.